# What is the difference between "in" and "at"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

While I know very well the difference between "**on**" and "**in**", or even between "**on**" and "**above**", I didn't get what the difference between "**in**" and "**at**" is, that many specific things strictly get just one of them (such as "at the university", "in the building", "in / at the morning".).

Is there a **clear** rule where to use this one (at) and where to use the second one (in)?

Comment: I'm afraid not; you'll have to learn all those things on a case-by-case basis. "At the morning" is not correct, but I couldn't tell you why. That's just the way it is.

Comment: @MrLister *Morning* is an extended period of time, so we use *in*; whereas *noon* is a specific time, so we use *at*. You are right, though. There is no general rule.

Answer (score 2):

The prepositions **in** and **at** can have many different functions. Sometimes there is no logical reason related to why we use one preposition and not another. Practice and experience will help you.

Generally speaking **at** is used to describe an **exact** location or **time.**

E.g.
 I will meet him **at** 2pm. ** **   = the **time** stated is very exact or specific**.**

E.g. I will meet you **at** the library. = the exact place you will meet.

You can also use **at** to describe where two lines cross or intersect such as two roads that cross or a corner.

E.g. I will meet you **at** highway 1. and Corfield St. = where these two roads cross each other.

E.g. Meet me **at** the corner of Corfied road and Murray St.= where these two streets connect or join at a corner.

We can also use **in** to talk about time and place.

E.g. I will see him **in** January.

E.g. I will see him **in** the new year .(or in 2018).

E.g.  Put the piano **in** the corner. = used to show a specific location within a house.

E.g. Please meet me **in** the library. = **in** refers to inside the library and **at** generally refers to meeting outside at the entrance (although English speakers  can use both to mean the inside).

As you can see, some of these functions are logical while others have to be committed to memory.  These are only a **few** uses and examples.

Also remember that some prepositions form part of a phrasal verb structure and don't function on their own and this confuses learners.

E.g. Please **drop in** when you have time.   **drop in = please visit**

Comment: I tried to address location; and you address time, also. Rome was not built in a day. But, I think one can come up with general rules.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between "in" and "at" in everyday speech and locating people or things geographically is this:

if a person or thing is at some place, it does not mean they are necessarily **in it**.

- John's **at home right now** playing with his children **outside**.

  The preposition **at** is used to describe the fact of a person or thing being at a geographical location but does not describe the person or thing actually being inside of the structure or place.
- John is **at home** but he is not in(side) his house. He's in the garden at the moment.
- **When people are at home** they are either inside their house or apartment but could be **on the porch  or veranda** or **in the garden**.

**If a person or thing therefore is at a place**, **they can also be inside some structure there**: in the building, in the house, in the store, in the garden, in the  park (considered to be a structure, semantically).

Bear in mind also that to be "in(side) a place or location" **does not mean the place or location has to be covered**: to be in the garden (gardens are generally open air), to be in the parking lot, to be in the woods. These places are considered to be places you can be in.

Finally, there are also **idiomatic uses of in** which means to be attending: to be in school or class (studying at a college or university); to be in church; to be in court These usages mean: to be attending school or church or court. Also, or to be institutionalized is: to be in hospital (BrE) and to be in the hospital (AmE). To be in the loony bin. :)

This should get you started but will not, by any means, cover every case.

Answer (score 1):

AT

*AT describes position at a specific point. 
It's very cold at the bottom of the ocean.

*AT is also used with a larger place (a store, bank, airport etc)
Let's meet at the bank

*AT is used before the names of group activities at a party, at a meeting, at a play, at a parade

IN

*IN refers to position within large areas or in spaces that surround something on all sides
My keys are in my bag. He is not in his office. The car is in the garage